# R raster stack mathematical conditioning operation

Tags: raster, r, stack, frequency

I am new to R and currently I am trying to create a drought frequency map using a stack of VHI rasters but, I still can't figure out a way. My attempt is as follows.

The stack of rasters contains data for a period of time as monthly averages (one month each) and values in each of those range from 0 to 1. What I want to do is classify these values to a binary output as pixels below a certain threshold (say <0.3) to be drought and calculate the number of occasions (frequency) that the said pixel is classified as a drought, and produce a single drought frequency raster.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe I haven't done enough research about this. Your ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: This is not an RStudio question. You are programming in R, and using RStudio to give you somewhere to type in an run R code. The R code can run in different environments, not just RStudio. If you tag your Q with "Rstudio" and not "R" it will slip past a lot of R experts' searches and you'll miss out. I'll re-tag it now, but only say "RStudio" when its a problem with the RStudio system itself and not with how to code something in R.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman for the tip. Will do immediately

Answer (score 2):

first I'll make a test stack using random numbers that should be the same shape as your data, using the `terra` package (I'm not using the older, `raster` packages):

```
> library(terra)
> r = function(){rast(matrix(runif(12),3,4))}
```

This function `r` creates a random 3x4 raster with values from 0 to 1. Now put eight of them in a stack:

```
> p = rast(list(r(),r(),r(),r(),r(),r(),r(),r()))
```

To compute if a cell is drought, you compare if its less than 0.3:

```
> drought = p < 0.3
```

You now have a stack of layers of the same shape as `p` but containing true and false values, coded as 1 and 0.

To count the total cells that are less than 3 in each location, you add up the cells in each layer of the stack using the `app` function:

```
> dfreq = app(drought, sum)
```

This returns a 3x4 single-layer raster of the number of times each location in the original `p` is greater than 0.3.

For convenience you should code this in a function:

```
compute_drought_freq = 
  function(s, thresh=0.3){
    return(app(s<thresh, sum))
  }
```

Then you can do:

```
dfreq = compute_drought_freq(p)
```

which is more readable and lets you change the drought threshold from 0.3 to 0.2 or 0.4 easily:

```
dfreq2 = compute_drought_freq(p, 0.4)
```

Comment: Wow this is really detailed explanation. Appreciate you taking your time for this. I will try this and come back with the result. Thanks fellow coder

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more concise version of Spacedman's solution:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrow=3, ncol=4, nlyr=8, vals=runif(8*12))

dfreq <- sum(r < 0.3)
```

Comment: Yes this actually is good. Thanks Robert❤️

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your inputs. Based on @Spacedman's answer, I was able to come at a solution. Below is the code, and also please note that this a company proprietary project so I cannot show the whole code of using NDVI and LST to produce VHI. Instead I will post the frequency calculation part for educational purposes for whoever interested in.

```
# Drought Frequency Calculation and Output
vhi_list <- list.files(vhi.path, pattern = paste(".tif$",sep = ""), full.names=TRUE)
vhi_stack <- stack(vhi_list)

# Defining thresholds for different values of VHI
thresholds <- list(5, 1, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 50)

# Loop through threshold values
for (i in thresholds){
  th = i/100
  name <- paste("DroughtFrequency", i, sep = "_")

  n.drought <-function(x, t=th){
    return(length(x[x<t]))
  }

  n <- calc(vhi_stack, fun = n.drought)

  droughtfreqency <- (n / length(vhi_list)) * 100
  writeRaster(droughtfreqency, file.path(drought_freqency.path, name), bylayer = TRUE, format = "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
}


# Custom Thresholds (change the value of i to  threshold * 100)
# 
# i = 40
# th = i/100
# name <- paste("DroughtFrequency", i, sep = "_")
# 
# n.drought <-function(x, t=th){
#   return(length(x[x<t]))
# }
# 
# n <- calc(vhi_stack, fun = n.drought)
# 
# droughtfreqency <- (n / length(vhi_list)) * 100
# writeRaster(droughtfreqency, file.path(drought_freqency.path, name), bylayer = TRUE, format = "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: Kindly accept this as answer.